# how to print a string 01 in csv generation without single cotes in joomla

Tags: csv, joomla

I generate a csv and in one field i take a variable which contain 01 .
But in csv it show only 1.
If i use single cotes it also show in csv like: '01', which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to convert it into a string ? You can use strval() in PHP to do that.